# Changing the animation for UINavigationController NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationbar

Right now when I use [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

The navigation bar flies in from right to left, is there a way to drop it down top to bottom?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = kAnimationDuration;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];
```

Worked great for me.

Source: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/25045-navigation-controller-custom-animation.html

Comment: Also, this: http://dmunsie.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/custom-animations-between-uiviewcontrollers/

Comment: impossible to read that site. Almost black letters over black background.

Comment: I had to change `animated` to `NO` otherwise it was choppy and messed up.