# pushing a view from bottom to top in uinavigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using the UINavigation controller.When i am pushing a view it comes from right to left. I want that view from bottom to up. how to do this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001466/changing-the-animation-for-uinavigationcontroller-navigationbar

Comment: I think you are looking for presentModalViewController

Answer (score 0):

if you are using simple designing like buttons only then you can use Action sheets as we use in bookmark section t comes from bottom to up .

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:<#(UIViewController *)modalViewController#> animated:<#(BOOL)animated#>];
```

Comment: This does not answer the question for @aravindhanarvi, because this does not use UINavigationController.

Comment: if i done using the presentModalViewController means the navigation bar is disappears.. how to resovle this