# how to create transition navigationcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, transform

I want transition between two `UIViewControllers` like push transition.
when I use push transition default my Views transform from right to left. but I want my Views transform left to right.

please guide me about that

Comment: Can you please give code examples?

Answer (score 0):

This may help. Although I believe there must be a better way.

```
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; // create the new view controller to "push"
    NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    NSMutableArray *mutableViewControllers = [viewControllers mutableCopy];
    NSInteger indexOfSelf = [mutableViewControllers indexOfObject:self];
    [mutableViewControllers insertObject:vc atIndex:indexOfSelf];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:mutableViewControllers];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // actually, it's a "pop" action
```

Comment: You won't have a back button if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I took the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001466/changing-the-animation-for-uinavigationcontroller-navigationbar) and modified it to look slightly cleaner and push from the desired direction. While it has the desired direction animation, there is some flickering in the navigation bar that I haven't been able to eliminate.

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.4f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewControllerHere animated:NO];
```

Also bear in mind that users are very used to the next view controller pushing in from the right. Think carefully before changing very basic things in the look/feel of standard items as you can confuse your users.

Comment: my friend how to change this transition for back button?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying you also want to change the transition direction when pressing the back button?

Comment: my friend I say when go to next page my view transition left to right and when click back button transition right to left

Comment: If you want to override the default behavior of the back button, you will need to create your own `UIBarButtonItem` and set it to the left navigation item. It will look slightly different from the default back button and lose some of the perks that come with it. You would just need to reverse the direction in the code above and manage your navigation stack manually.